# Signing using PKCS#11 tokens

Tags: java, jce

Trying to read a PKCS#11 config stream and then extract certificate and private key. It is working but when trying to create a cipher instance of the private key, getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a byte[]
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_ATTRIBUTE.getBigInteger(CK_ATTRIBUTE.java:153)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11RSAPrivateKey.fetchValues(P11Key.java:498)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Key$P11RSAPrivateKey.getModulus(P11Key.java:524)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.translatePrivateKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:289)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineTranslateKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:226)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.toRSAKey(RSAKeyFactory.java:129)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.init(RSACipher.java:265)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineInit(RSACipher.java:210)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:805)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:867)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1252)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1189)
at com.digio.offlinesign.test.test.main(test.java:94)
```

Any suggestions on how to read?

The private key is of the instance P11Key$P11RSAPrivateKey

Loading the keystore here:

```
    String libraryPath="name=eToken\nlibrary=" + "/usr/local/lib/wdProxKeyUsbKeyTool/libwdpkcs_ProxKey.dylib";
    ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(libraryPath.getBytes());
    Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
    cArg[0] = InputStream.class;
    Class pkcs11Class = Class.forName("sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11");
    Object providerPKCS11 = pkcs11Class.getConstructor(cArg).newInstance(new Object[] { pkcs11ConfigStream });
    Provider provider = (Provider) providerPKCS11;
    if (Security.getProvider(provider.getName())!=null){
        Security.removeProvider(provider.getName());
    }
    Security.addProvider(provider);
    java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
    String password = ""; //password here for the token
    try {
        keyStore.load(null, password.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Getting the private key from the keystore:

```
    List<PrivateKey> privateKeyList = new ArrayList<PrivateKey>();
    String alias = null;
    PrivateKey pk = null;
    java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        alias = aliases.nextElement();
        pk = (PrivateKey)keyStore.getKey(alias, password.toCharArray());
        if(pk!=null)
        {
            privateKeyList.add(pk);
        }
    }
```

Now when creating a cipher instance here, the exception is thrown:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(pk.getAlgorithm());
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the code and the actual data you input. Please create a [mcve] and elaborate on whats going on in detail. Giving you _guesses_ of what might be the cause is out of the scope of how this site works. You will only get answers when its clear what the issue is and what will fix it. Downvoted and voting to close for unclear and missing details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, added relevant code snippet for the same.

Comment: HSMs traditionally prohibit extracting the private key(s), at least without special privileges and often tools. Try creating the Cipher with `Cipher.getInstance(pk.getAlgorithm(), "PKCS11")` and it should be able to use the key on the device (i.e. without extracting). Incidentally, I don't see any point to all the reflective code instead of simply doing `provider = new SunPKCS11 (inputstream)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just trying something that's why the reflective code. However, I am able to sign using the same code for other HSM. This particular module is throwing the error.